# Post request using loopj AysyncHttpClient android library

Tags: android, rest, google-cloud-endpoints, http-request, androidhttpclient

When trying to post into a google cloud endpoint via REST I get org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request

when trying using http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ on my android app. I have made this post in POSTMAN REST client without an error.

Here is the bit of code

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams p = new RequestParams();
p.put("test", "123");
client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.post("https://flash-energy-585.appspot.com/_ah/api/reminders/v1/reminders/createreminder",p, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
            // Successfully got a response
            System.out.println(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
            System.out.println(error.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: `"Content-Type", "application/json"` would indicate you are sending json, but I think you are sending url encoded params.

Comment: How can I change that?

Comment: figured it out! I was making URL encoded requests.